# Git Pipeline Fails ModuleNotFoundError of Own Module

Tags: git, modulenotfounderror, merge-request

I want to merge my feature branch into the general development branch.
The feature branch contains new modules being used. When I run the testing pipeline in the merge request, it fails due to a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I'm new using Git and am not sure why this happens.
Let's pretend my development branch is called `develop` and the feature branch `feature`. The branch `develop` contains a folder structure including `folder/subfolder1` and `feature` additionally `folder/subfolder2`.
A script that is run by the testing pipeline includes now:

```
from folder.subfolder2 import myFunc
```

This calls the `ModuleNotFoundError`. The function hereby exists and when I run the test script outside of the git pipeline it works as well.
Is there some place in the `develop` branch where I have to create a module so the new function and folder of the `feature` branch can be included?

I tried to look into the files of the `develop` branch if there is some line where the new own modules need to be added but didn't find anything.